What verbal tests are used to identify pseudepigrapha?
This question is about how features like theological redundancy, rephrasing and emphasis on reported speech are used in literary analysis of pseudepigrapha.
For example: the letter of Saint Abgar (whose story forms part of the liturgy of the Syriac Orthodox Church - https://syriacorthodoxresources.org/Feast/Abgar.html)
I've pasted the Greek version from Eusebius (c.325BC) below as it takes a few minutes to bring it up on Perseus Project.
For these letters, an argument for theological redundancy would run that their description of Christ's ministry and the lessons derived from it can quickly be found in Matthew's and John's gospels - entirely, and without adding to or deviating from them. If this is admitted it next seems as if the gospels' verbs are placed into reported speech, with the writer's repeated "I have heard that" referring to his own usage of the gospel source. Lastly the use of cognate forms (e.g. καταγογγύζουσί < Ἐγόγγυζον ; πᾶσαν νόσον < μακρονοσίᾳ) might be to differentiate or to adapt for dialect differences in a new milieu.
But since all these things could work in either direction - and when it would be strange to base an apocryphon in Matthew whilst making Abgar look less pious than Matthew's Roman centurion - is there a strict order in which these tests are applied? Is there a baseline against which the rephrasing can be compared?

https://archive.org/details/eusebius-ecclesiastical-history-loeb/page/n139/mode/2up?q=Abgar
http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=1.13&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0640


ΑΝΤΙΓΡΑΦΟΝ ΕΠΙΣΤΟΛΗΣ ΓΡΑΦΕΙΣΗΣ ΥΠΟ ΑΒΓΑΡΟΥ ΤΟΠΑΡΧΟΥ ΤΩΙ ΙΗΣΟΥ ΚΑΙ
ΠΕΜΦΘΕΙΣΗΣ ΑΥΤΩΙ ΔΙ᾿ ΑΝΑΝΙΟΥ ΤΑΧΥΔΡΟΜΟΥ ΕΙΣ ΙΕΡΟΣΟΛΥΜΑ ‘ [6] Ἄβγαρος
Οὐχαμα τοπάρχης Ἰησοῦ σωτῆρι ἀγαθῷ ἀναφανέντι ἐν τόπῳ Ἱεροσολύμων
χαίρειν. ἤκουσταί μοι τὰ περὶ σοῦ καὶ τῶν σῶν ἰαμάτων, ὡς ἄνευ
φαρμάκων καὶ βοτανῶν ὑπὸ σοῦ γινομένων. 101 ὡς γὰρ λόγος, τυφλοὺς
ἀναβλέπειν ποιεῖς, 102 χωλοὺς περιπατεῖν, καὶ λεπροὺς καθαρίζεις, καὶ
ἀκάθαρτα πνεύματα καὶ δαίμονας ἐκβάλλεις, καὶ τοὺς ἐν μακρονοσίᾳ
βασανιζομένους θεραπεύεις, καὶ νεκροὺς ἐγείρεις. [7] καὶ ταῦτα πάντα
ἀκούσας περὶ σοῦ, κατὰ νοῦν ἐθέμην τὸ ἕτερον τῶν δύο, ἢ ὅτι σὺ εἶ ὁ
θεὸς καὶ καταβὰς ἀπὸ τοῦ οὐρανοῦ ποιεῖς ταῦτα, ἢ υἱὸς εἶ τοῦ θεοῦ
ποιῶν ταῦτα. [8] διὰ τοῦτο τοίνυν γράψας ἐδεήθην σου σκυλῆναι πρός με
καὶ τὸ πάθος, ὃ ἔχω, θεραπεῦσαι. [9] καὶ γὰρ ἤκουσα ὅτι καὶ Ἰουδαῖοι
καταγογγύζουσί σου 103 καὶ βούλονται κακῶσαί σε. πόλις δὲ μικροτάτη
μοί ἐστι καὶ σεμνή, ἥτις ἐξαρκεῖ ἀμφοτέροις.’


Abgar, ruler of Edessa, to Jesus the good physician who has appeared
in the country of Jerusalem, greeting. I have heard the reports of you
and of your cures as performed by you without medicines or herbs. For
it is said that you make the blind to see and the lame to walk, that
you cleanse lepers and cast out impure spirits and demons, and that
you heal those afflicted with lingering disease, and raise the dead.
And having heard all these things concerning you, I have concluded
that one of two things must be true: either you are God, and, having
come down from heaven, you do these things, or else you, who does
these things, are the son of God. I have therefore written to you to
ask you if you would take the trouble to come to me and heal all the
ill which I suffer. For I have heard that the Jews are murmuring
against you and are plotting to injure you. But I have a very small
yet noble city which is great enough for us both.[19]


ΤΑ ΑΝΤΙΓΡΑΦΕΝΤΑ ΥΗΟ
ΙΗΣΟΥ ΔΙΑ ΑΝΑΝΙΟΥ ΤΑΧΥΔΡΟΜΟΥ ΤΟΠΑΡΧΗΙ ΑΒΓΑΡΩΙ [10] 104 ‘Μακάριος εἶ
πιστεύσας ἐν ἐμοί, μὴ ἑορακώς 105 με. γέγραπται γὰρ περὶ ἐμοῦ τοὺς
ἑορακότας 106 με μὴ πιστεύσειν ἐν ἐμοί, καὶ ἵνα οἱ μὴ ἑορακότες 107 με
αὐτοὶ πιστεύσωσι καὶ ζήσονται. περὶ δὲ οὗ [p. 90] ἔγραψάς μοι ἐλθεῖν
πρὸς σέ, δέον ἐστὶ πάντα δἰ ἃ ἀπεστάλην ἐνταῦθα, πληρῶσαι καὶ μετὰ τὸ
πληρῶσαι οὕτως ἀναληφθῆναι πρὸς τὸν ἀποστείλαντά με. καὶ ἐπειδὰν
ἀναληφθῶ, ἀποστελῶ σοί τινα τῶν μαθητῶν μου, ἵνα ἰάσηταί σου τὸ πάθος
καὶ ζωήν σοι καὶ τοῖς σὺν σοὶ παράσχηται.’


Blessed are you who hast believed in me without having seen me. For it
is written concerning me, that they who have seen me will not believe
in me, and that they who have not seen me will believe and be saved.
But in regard to what you have written me, that I should come to you,
it is necessary for me to fulfill all things here for which I have
been sent, and after I have fulfilled them, thus to be taken up again
to him that sent me. But after I have been taken up, I will send to
you one of my disciples, that he may heal your disease and give life
to you and yours.


τυφλοὶ ἀναβλέπουσιν καὶ χωλοὶ περιπατοῦσιν, λεπροὶ καθαρίζονται καὶ κωφοὶ ἀκούουσιν, καὶ νεκροὶ ἐγείρονται - - Matthew 11:5
ἔδωκεν αὐτοῖς ἐξουσίαν πνευμάτων ἀκαθάρτων ὥστε ἐκβάλλειν αὐτὰ καὶ θεραπεύειν πᾶσαν νόσον καὶ πᾶσαν μαλακίαν - - Matthew 10:1
Ἐγόγγυζον οὖν οἱ Ἰουδαῖοι - - John 6:41
“Ὅτι ἑώρακάς με, πεπίστευκας; μακάριοι οἱ μὴ ἰδόντες καὶ πιστεύσαντες.” - - John 20:29
Ἄφες ἄρτι· οὕτως γὰρ πρέπον ἐστὶν ἡμῖν πληρῶσαι πᾶσαν δικαιοσύνην - - Matthew 3:15
But compare: “Lord, I do not deserve to have you come under my roof. But just say the word, and my servant will be healed. - - Matthew 8:8

There are no "verbal texts" - just content tests.
